# Barplot a value by date

Tags: r

I have a data frame in R that looks like this:

```
    mo  birds   maxdate
10-Dec  65  12/24/2010
10-Nov  30  11/5/2010
10-Oct  30  10/4/2010
10-Sep  28  9/30/2010
11-Apr  19  4/21/2011
11-Aug  14  8/13/2011
11-Dec  14  12/12/2011
11-Feb  47  2/1/2011
11-Jan  59  1/1/2011
11-Jul  14  7/4/2011
```

I would like to barplot the number of birds by mo with the dates in chronological order on the x axis. I have already summarized the data so there is only one value for 'birds' for each month.

I tried this:

```
    p <- ggplot(mc, aes(mo, birds))+
    +   stat_summary(fun.y = sum, geom = "bar")

    mc$month <- as.Date(cut(mc$maxdate, breaks = "month"))
```

But got this:

```
    Error in cut.default(mc$maxdate, breaks = "month") : 'x' must be numeric
```

I cannot seem to find and answer Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is `class(mc$maxdate)` ?

Comment: What's `class(mx$maxdate)` return?

Comment: What are you trying to get in mc$months?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `maxdate` is a `factor`, `cut` doesn't know that it's a date so it doesn't operate the way you expect. Here's how you can convert the factor to a date and use cut properly

```
mc$month <- cut(as.Date(as.character(mc$maxdate), format="%m/%d/%Y"),
   breaks="month")
```